# Mount Network Drives when Sandbox Mode is ON

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I have implemented Network drive mounting using `NetFSMountURLSync` with different protocols (AFP, SMB, NFS and NFS (Final cut protocol)). Below mentioned is my code to achieve it.

Example url: smb://10.64.104.215/

Example mountpath: file:///Volumes/

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mountURLString];

NSURL *mountpath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/" isDirectory:YES];

CFMutableDictionaryRef mountOpts = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(mountOpts, kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey, CFSTR("MountAtMountDir"));

CFArrayRef mountpoints = NULL;

NSInteger error = NetFSMountURLSync(
                                    (__bridge CFURLRef) url,
                                    (__bridge CFURLRef) mountpath,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL ,
                                    0,
                                    mountOpts,
                                    &mountpoints);
```

It works fine when Sandbox Mode is OFF but the above code doesn’t work when Sandbox mode is ON. It returns me error as 1 which is `“Operation not permitted”` according to the Error.h file. I know there are restrictions in Sandbox mode, but it's important for my application to mount network drives because it's one of the core features of my application. How can i achieve the Network drive mount feature to work when Sandbox mode is ON. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by changing, my mountpath to a location within my app's container. I received this solution from one of the Developer Tech Support guy on apple forum.

Below is the edited and working code for the same:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mountURLString];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

NSURL *mountpath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", documentsDirectory] isDirectory:YES];

CFMutableDictionaryRef mountOpts = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(mountOpts, kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey, CFSTR("MountAtMountDir"));

CFArrayRef mountpoints = NULL;

NSInteger error = NetFSMountURLSync(
                                    (__bridge CFURLRef) url,
                                    (__bridge CFURLRef) mountpath,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL ,
                                    0,
                                    mountOpts,
                                    &mountpoints);
```

Comment: I'm having a related problem. When I set kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey to false and I specify a mount point the location the mount actually happens is under the mount point I specify. If I set it to true, the call fails, with return code 1. Any idea how to force it to mount where I want?